# NSFetchedResultsController sectionNameKeyPath not respecting fetchBatchSize

Tags: swift, core-data

Sorry Core Data noob here...

I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` on a `UITableViewController`. The data in the Entity contains `timestamps`. As `sectionID` I want to use the date in the section header. But when I use the `sectionNameKeyPath`, Core Data loads all the data instead of respecting the `fetchBatchSize`.

Is what I want possible, and if so what am I doing wrong here. And if this is not possible using the `fetchedResultsController`, what alternatives are there?

**The fetchedResultController:**

```
class func transactionsResultController(wallet: Wallet, batchSize: Int? = nil) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Transaction> {
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<Transaction> in
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Transaction> = Transaction.fetchRequest()

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY wallet == %@", wallet)

        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = batchSize ?? 20

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Transaction.timestamp), ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: nil)

        do {
            try aFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let error {
            debug(error)
        }
        return aFetchedResultsController
    }()

    return fetchedResultsController }
```

**The section identifier:**

```
extension Transaction{

var sectionIdentifier: String {
    let date = self.timestamp!.timestampToUTCDate(currency: (self.senderId?.currency!)!)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "en_US_POSIX")
    var components = DateComponents()
    let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
    components.day = comps.day
    components.month = comps.month
    components.year = comps.year
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let reconstructedDate = calendar.date(from: components)!

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
    let prettyDay = dateFormatter.string(from: reconstructedDate)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let prettyMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: reconstructedDate)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY"
    let prettyYear = dateFormatter.string(from: reconstructedDate)

    if (calendar.isDateInToday(reconstructedDate)){
        return "Today"
    }
    else if (calendar.isDateInYesterday(reconstructedDate)){
        return "Yesterday"
    }

    return "\(prettyDay) \(prettyMonth) \(prettyYear)"
} }
```

Thanks for taking time to read and help ;)

Answer (score 0):

`fetchedResultsController` does not respect batchSize.  A `fetchedResultsController` works by doing a fetch with a predicate and then monitoring the context to see when items are added or removed to the fetchedObjects list and updating accordingly. If a changed item passes the predicate, but is not on the list, it is an insert; if a changed item fails the predicate, but is on the list, it is a delete, otherwise it is an update or move.  If it respected batch size it would be much harder for a `fetchedResultsController` to know if a changed item passing the predicate but is not on the list is an insert or a an item that is passed the batchSize.

Here are two possible solutions:

1. Have the `fetchedResultsController` fetch everything with a batchSize limit.  Then in your UI limit the amount that you display.  Do NOT limit it by making less rows in you tableView (NUMBER_OF_ROWS -= min(REAL_NUMBER, SIZE_LIMIT).  There are too many annoying edge cases that you have to keep track of - like moves and inserts that push will push an item out of the list at the bottom, and delegate evens for items that aren't displayed.  They aren't super hard to deal with but they can add up and if you mess up the tableView will stop working.  It is far easier just to declare that the row height for indexPath above a certain index is 0.  That way you can still respond to the delegated fetchedResultsController event like normal, but the UI won't display the cells.
2. Add another predicate that will limit your results to the desired amount.  For example, if you items are order by date and you only want the most recent add a predicate "date > CUT_OFF_DATE".  To figure out the correct cut of date to use you do a single fetch where batchSize=1 and batchOffset equals the max amount that you want to display.  Then use the the date of that object in your predicate to create the fetchedResultsController. While the limit will be respect when the controller loads, as more items are inserted the amount displayed will increase beyond the initial display limit.

If you have a lot of item and want to limit the amount that get into memory the second option is better.

If you want to limit the amount displayed in each section (not just a global limit for the whole table) then the first option can support that, but the second option can't.